# How to rewrite multiple parameter url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have some problems with url rewriting.
I have url's like that:

```
http://url.com/?page=post&id=1&title=astanadaghy-qorghanys-ministrliigiiniinh-janyndaghy-jarylys-jayly-janha-aqparat
```

I want something like that:

```
http://url.com/posts/1-astanadaghy-qorghanys-ministrliigiiniinh-janyndaghy-jarylys-jayly-janha-aqparat.html
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?posts/([0-9]+)-([^\.*]+).html$ index.php?page=post&id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```